# Little bits of food

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle, steganography

You will come across a question.

Answer it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling! Questions like these, where the solving strategy is not explicitly given, are usually tagged [enigmatic-puzzles]. I've added the tag for you.

Comment: I guess the steganography tag is relevant here.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The answer is

> Chicago

Following Dan Russell's partial answer:

> Taking the 2 least significant bits of each pixel, I get this image: [image]

Thanks to @f'' in the comments, the interpretation of this is:

> Those are pictures of a clipboard, a bin and Kim Dotcom, forming pastebin.com.
>  Accessing http://pastebin.com/L0szeSrH we see the question "What city?" and a picture of a track which appears to be located in Chicago, more specifically the [UIC-Halsted station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIC%E2%80%93Halsted_%28CTA_station%29).

Comment: Nicely done. Any ideas about the initial bready picture? Random/relevant?

Comment: @DanRussell They're "little bits" of food, get it?

Comment: In retrospect: duh. Remind me not to post things at 2 am.

Comment: Out of interest: how do you extract the low bits of the pixels?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I used the Python Imaging Library: http://pastebin.com/zXM5HQSn

Answer (score 14):

Partial answer.  By:

> Dropping the brightness of the image way down, you get:  
>  [image]  
>  So there's definitely a dude in there... (What has two thumbs and loves toast? This guy!) But I don't think that's enough, and given the tag I don't think I have the expertise to go further.

Comment: I'll have to keep this trick in mind for detecting such tricks in the future ...